# Docker run, no response

Tags: docker

I'm implementing docker: `docker build -t`  from the following docker file.

```
**FROM centos:7**

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install wget
RUN wget http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/linux64/jq && chmod 755 jq && mv jq /bin
RUN yum -y install openssh-clients
RUN yum -y install cronie
RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk
RUN yum -y install nmap-ncat
RUN yum -y install ntpdate 
ENTRYPOINT tail -f /dev/null
```

After executing the build, even if `docker run -it` is executed, there is no response and I cannot login to the container. 
However, when you run `docker ps`, the container is running. 
Why is not the response coming back? I am wondering if it is a description of ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: it should be : `docker exec -it container_id bash` or `docker exec -it comtainer_id /bin/sh`

Comment: As you pointed out, the `docker exec -it container_id bash`is valid. If I actually execute that command I can also log in to the container. However, even if i create a container with `docker run`, the response will not be returned, so I need to restart the terminal. I am annoying about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting container in detached mode.

`-d, --detach                         Run container in background and print container ID`

```
#>docker build -t myimg .
#>docker run -d --name mycontainer myimg
#>docker exec -it mycontainer bash
[root@mycontainer/]# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 11976 Apr  2 18:39 anaconda-post.log
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 May 25 06:51 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   340 May 25 06:53 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    66 May 25 06:53 etc
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 May 25 06:51 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 May 25 06:51 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 media
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 985 root root     0 May 25 06:53 proc
dr-xr-x---   1 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     6 May 25 06:52 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 May 25 06:51 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     6 Apr 11 04:59 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 May  2 14:37 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root     6 May 25 06:52 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    44 May 25 06:51 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    52 May 25 06:51 var
[root@mycontainer/]#
```

Comment: It seems good to start with detached mode. If so, i do not worry about the response . so i will operate in this way from next! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**ENTRYPOINT** is used to set default **init** process in container, which can be overwritten by command line.

`docker run container_image` will use **ENTRYPOINT** as **init**.

`docker run container_image prog` will ignore **ENTRYPOINT** and use prog as **init**.

Comment: Thank you. If i want to login directly to this container, i will overwrite ENTRYPOINT.